# Not clear about the overall structure of my model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have recently started working on deep neural networks.
I am currently creating a model for emotion detection using Kaggle fer2013.csv dataset.
My model is compiling but when I try to train it gives a ValueError error  `'Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 7) are incompatible'`

```
ValueError: in user code:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:756 train_step
    y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:203 __call__
    loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:152 __call__
    losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:256 call  **
    return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1537 categorical_crossentropy
    return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4833 categorical_crossentropy
    target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
    raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 7) are incompatible
```

There are a total of 7 emotions among which one is to be detected.
Images were 48X48 .

```
num_features = 64
num_labels = 7
width,height = 48,48
```

Code I used to create my model

```
model = Sequential()
# Block 1 of NN
model.add(Conv2D(num_features, kernel_size=3,activation='relu',input_shape = x_train.shape[1:],padding = 'same'))
model.add(Conv2D(num_features, kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2, strides = 2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

#BLock 2 of NN
model.add(Conv2D(2*num_features, kernel_size = (3,3),activation = 'relu',))
model.add(Conv2D(2*num_features, kernel_size = (3,3),activation = 'relu',))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2, strides = 2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

#BLock 3 of NN
model.add(Conv2D(4*num_features, kernel_size = (3,3),activation = 'relu',))
model.add(Conv2D(4*num_features, kernel_size = (3,3),activation = 'relu',))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2, strides = 2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())

#FC layers
model.add(Dense(16*num_features,activation = 'relu' ))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(16*num_features,activation = 'relu' ))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

#Output Layer
model.add(Dense(num_labels,activation = 'softmax'))
```

[MODEL SUMMARY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJGN1.png)

PLEASE HELP ME. I AM STUCK AND REALLY DO NOT KNOW WHAT TO DO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to one-hot encode your dependent variable (Y) and reshape if necessary, because your output layer is (None,7).

```
import keras
import numpy as np
labels=np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]]).reshape(-1,1)
keras.utils.to_categorical(labels)
```

Output:

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Reshaping doesnot help. Still is giving the exact same error.

Comment: Thank you..the error is now resolved. Had to one hot encode the test_y and train_y since we are doing a multi-class classification.Thank yyou for pointing it out.